# CSV file handling - My program wont output anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have made a CSV file where it stores a book, its author and the year it was published (this file is made from user input). I then made it where the program will ask the user for a starting year and an ending year, and the program should display all the books from the data set published during that time frame. For some reason, my code outputs nothing after the user inputs a start and end year, so I'm not sure what the underlying problem is within my code

Here is my code so far:

```
import csv

amount = int(input("How many records would you like to store: "))
count = 0

with open("Books.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["", "Book", "Author", "Year released"])

while count < amount:

    book = input("Enter a book: ")
    author = input("Enter the Author: ")
    year = input("Enter the year it released: ")

    headers = [count, book, author, year]
    with open("Books.csv", "a", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(headers)

    count += 1

books = []

start_year = int(input("What start year?"))
end_year = int(input("What end year?"))

with open("Books.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        count, book, author, release_year = row
        if release_year is int:
            if int(release_year) > start_year and int(release_year) < end_year:
                books.append(book)
print(books)
```

The output:

```
How many records would you like to store: 3
Enter a book: To kill a mockingbird
Enter the Author: Harper Lee
Enter the year it released: 1960
Enter a book: The Great Gatsby
Enter the Author: F.Scott Fitzgerald
Enter the year it released: 1922
Enter a book: Pride and Prejudice
Enter the Author: Jane Austen
Enter the year it released: 1813
What start year?1900
What end year?2000
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Stackoverflow, so dont judge me to harshly :) There are multiple ways to solve your problem and enhance your code. So lets get to it.

1. As the people mentioned `release_year` is returned as a string and you will need to transform it into the integer type, so that you can work with it appropriately.
2. The csv reader also returns the header as row, you could skip it. But to do that I would check if the var `release_year` contains a digit, if not it is a header. If it contains digits it should be transformed into an integer. This makes your Code more robust, because now you can apply this to files with and without headers.
3. To check wether `release_year` is an integer, I think you can use the `isinstance` [method](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-type-isinstance/) like I suggested below.
4. For ease of writing and reading you can write `start_year < release_year < end_year` Python supports this style, and it is easier to read.
   This would be my suggestion on how to solve your problem.

   with open("Books.csv", "r") as file:
   reader = csv.reader(file)
   for row in reader:

   ```
    count, book, author, release_year = row

    # check if var contains digits if so transform type
    if release_year.isdigit():
        release_year = int(release_year)

    # header will not pass this
    if isinstance(release_year, int):

        # python supports this style 
        if start_year < release_year < end_year:
            books.append(book)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can either skip first row or you can use isdigit() to check if it is a digit

```
if release_year.isdigit():
            print("hellp", release_year)
            if int(release_year) > start_year and int(release_year) < end_year:
                books.append(book)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the statement `if release_year is int` which will always be false because the CSV reader will always give you strings (you can test that by printing the type of release_year like so `print(type(release_year))`.

Also you should skip the first row.

```py
books = []

start_year = int(input("What start year?"))
end_year = int(input("What end year?"))

with open("Books.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    # skip the first row containing headers
    next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        count, book, author, release_year = row
        if release_year:
            if int(release_year) > start_year and int(release_year) < end_year:
                books.append(book)
print(books)
```